# Is possible to use NearBy API with out Proximity API?

Tags: android, ibeacon, ibeacon-android, google-beacon-platform

I'm using a beacon that can work either with iBeacon or Eddystone, I create a scanner that has a service in the background which scans each 10 secs for beacons, similar to the android-beacon-library, but I was thinking that I could use the NearBy API to get the beacons with out the scan service, Is that possible?, I don't want to use the ProximityAPI to register the beacons because these beacons will be out there with out the need to register them.

Comment: What precisely do you wish to accomplish with the Nearby API?

Comment: Just detect the beacons, without having an external library or service running in the background.

Answer (score 3):

**In order to use the Nearby API, your beacons must both be registered with the Google cloud, and have attachments as described [here.](https://developers.google.com/beacons/proximity/attachments)**

The way the Nearby API works, you create a `MessageListener` and subscribe to get callbacks when beacons are found with messages attached to them:

> When subscribing, your app will automatically receive any messages that you've attached to BLE beacons, in addition to any messages published by your app on other devices.

https://developers.google.com/nearby/messages/android/get-beacon-messages

If there aren't any messages attached to them, you won't get any callbacks

Comment: Yes, I read the same think but it just not make sense to me, because in order to get the message attached, they first need to find the beacon, so I'm thinking that the google play services should have something in the back scanning for beacons and I didn't want to add something else.

Comment: Yes, Google Play Services certainly does need to scan for the beacon first in order to expose any attached messages.  But that doesn't mean Google Play Services exposes the raw detection event in the absence of an available message.  I do not believe there is any public API that provides access to this detection event.

Comment: David's answers are dead-on here. There is no way, currently, using Nearby Mesages, to see the raw beacon events. Nearby Messages is primarily for messaging between devices, and if the device in question (the beacon) doesn't have any registered data (messages) attached to it, it will skip them.